# Повторить код несколько раз

Tags: python

Как сделать так чтобы мой код повторялся несколько раз так чтобы я мог каждый раз вписывать новые числа

```
x=int(input('')) 
y=int(input('')) 
if x>10 or y>10:
    print('yes') 
else:
    print('no')
```

Comment: Сделайте цикл...

Comment: А как его сделать я недавно начал изучать python и не знаю как его сделать

Comment: https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/2.7.php

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте бесконечный while цикл:

```
while True:
    x=int(input(''))
    y=int(input(''))
    if x>10 or y>10:
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```